# Google App Maker driver picker files

Tags: google-app-maker

In App Maker we have drive picker widget that will save files in current user google drive.

When a user uploads a file to his drive, the other users in the application should access the file from the uploaded URL. Or is there a option to configure a common drive for all users to save there files.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really an answer but I can't comment due to the my lack of points. You can use team drive or shared folder depending on your needs. When the upload is complete, you can move the file. You can either bind it to OnDocumentSelect of widget or do it when the user clicks the final approval depending on your flow.

Alternatively, you can let people drop into that folder and use appmaker to read the contents of the folder and let user pick. I am not sure which one is better.

Comment: Oh Is it possible to use team drive in appmaker, how to configure it.

Comment: You can get a list of team drives but I don't currently see an option to add it as a parent to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be eventually addressed by [Team Drives](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/get-started-team-drive/), but it is not supported by App Maker at this time. Meanwhile, you can use [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) (Server Script) to put uploaded files into a shared folder:

```js
// ID of the folder shared with all interested parties
var folderId = '9A18nXnY1C0amK0WCPI1WqMPObDj';
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

var fileId = 'JI09KJkjIU7kjUYNdeIcNK1nFG8a';
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

folder.addFile(file);
```

or explicitly grant permissions to the file:

```js
var fileId = 'JI09KJkjIU7kjUYNdeIcNK1nFG8a';
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

file.addCommenter('leia@sw.com');
file.addViewer('tony@marvel.com');
file.addEditors(['james@st.com', 'jon@got.com']);
```

Comment: Thanks pavel, Appmaker does not support Team drives right